# Call a function in a functional component in another file React

Tags: reactjs

I have a login component that is in its own separate file, the component, however, needs to set a state in a parent component. Passing the state setter function as a props fails:

```
Uncaught TypeError: props.setLogState is not a function
```

Within the App(parent) component, this is my code:

```
{logState === 2 ? (
          <Login setLogState={setLogState} getTickers={getTickers} />
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
```

I am importing the Login component as follows: `import Login from "./Components/login";`
And in the Login component I export it as follows `export default Login;`

Within the Login component there is a function called login, which is called when the user clicks the login button in the same component, and part of the functionality is to call the parent `setLogState` and change the state. Below is how I call it.

```
  props.setLogState(1);
```

It seems that then login component does not read the props given. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Are you importing props in the child component, like this: export const login = (props) => {}

Comment: Yes. const Login = (props) => { ....

Comment: The problems was coming from another instance of a similar components. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

You must not be passing the setState function correctly. With the limited code you have provided it will be difficult to help analyze your specific problem, below a working example.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Child = (props) => {
  return (
    <input onChange={(e) => props.setStateProp(e.target.value)} />
  );
};
const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState();

  return (
    <div>
      <Child setStateProp={setState} />
      {state && <p>State: {state}</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```